# Where are the custom images of the asset data preview stored? (Python)

Tags: python, materials, asset-browser

I'm trying to figure out in the API where the custom image of a material in the Asset Browser, but I can't figure out where it is stored.

Note: I'm not talking about the image rendered by Cycles, but rather an image that I loaded manually through the operator `bpy.ops.ed.lib_id_load_custom_preview()`

I would have expected to find the preview stored in some property like this:

`D.materials['My mat'].asset_data.preview`

Unfortunately it seems difficult to understand where it is stored, and whether it is possible to obtain it via the python API.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DNR: Looks like another incomplete part of the asset browser Python API.

It's definitely not in the [asset data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AssetMetaData.html#bpy.types.AssetMetaData) and there doesn't appear to be an [asset op](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/assets.py) that accesses the information.  I think it's yet another part of the Asset Browser that  currently doesn't have an API.  The only thing I could find relevant was [this addon](https://github.com/johnnygizmo/asset_snapshot/blob/main/__init__.py) for creating custom snapshots. It validates your assumption about how to read the data; but doesn't appear to use the existing data before it creates a new image.